# How to programatically open a new 'hidden' PowerPoint/Word/Excel window for processing

Tags: vba

I'm working with the Excel, PowerPoint and Word OLE objects and my aim is to 'Silently' convert a document to a PDF.

Currently I have the below non-silent methods:

```
Class PowerPointExporter
    Sub Export(path As String, newPath As String)
        Dim application As New PowerPoint.Application
        Dim presentation As PowerPoint.Presentation = application.Presentations.Open(path)
        presentation.SaveAs(newPath, PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPDF)
        presentation.Close()
        application.Quit()
    End Sub
End Class
Class ExcelExporter
    Sub Export(path As String, newPath As String)
        Dim application As New Excel.Application
        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(path)
        wb.SaveAs(newPath, Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF)
        wb.Close()
        application.Quit()
    End Sub
End Class
Class WordExporter
    Sub Export(path As String, newPath As String)
        Dim application As New Word.Application
        Dim doc As Word.Document = application.Documents.Open(path)
        doc.SaveAs2(newPath, Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF)
        doc.Close()
        application.Quit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

So my question is, how can I make these silent? I.E. Hide the window / move the window offscreen, or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PowerPoint:

```
  Set PPTObj = New PowerPoint.Application
  If Debugging Then
    Set PPTClinic = PPTObj.Presentations.Open(fileName:=PPTFileName, ReadOnly:=msoCTrue, WithWindow:=msoTrue) 'this will prevent the window from being visible
  Else
    Set PPTClinic = PPTObj.Presentations.Open(fileName:=PPTFileName, ReadOnly:=msoCTrue, WithWindow:=msoFalse) 'this will prevent the window from being visible
  End If
```

Note the `WithWindow` parameter at the end.

For Excel:

```
  Set XLobj = New Excel.Application
  If Debugging Then
    XLobj.Visible = True
  Else
    XLobj.Visible = False
  End If
```

I haven't done anything in Word for quite a number of years, but it's probably something similar. I'll see what Google says...

Ah, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/application-visible-property-word) it is for Word:

```
Application.Visible = False
```

Sorry, no nifty example whipped up - I took the first two from my existing code, the last one was just borrowed from the linked page.